# Overriding _getHtml function in topmenu.php makes navbar disappear

Tags: magento2, frontend, topmenu

I'm trying to override the __getHtml function in topmenu.php

```
class Topmenu extends \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu
{
    protected function _getHtml(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node $menuTree,
        $childrenWrapClass,
        $limit,
        array $colBrakes = []
    ) {
        $html = '';

        $children = $menuTree->getChildren();
        $childLevel = $this->getChildLevel($menuTree->getLevel());
        $this->removeChildrenWithoutActiveParent($children, $childLevel);

        $counter = 1;
        $childrenCount = $children->count();

        $parentPositionClass = $menuTree->getPositionClass();
        $itemPositionClassPrefix = $parentPositionClass ? $parentPositionClass . '-' : 'nav-';

        /** @var Node $child */
        foreach ($children as $child) {
            $child->setLevel($childLevel);
            $child->setIsFirst($counter === 1);
            $child->setIsLast($counter === $childrenCount);
            $child->setPositionClass($itemPositionClassPrefix . $counter);

            $outermostClassCode = '';
            $outermostClass = $menuTree->getOutermostClass();

            if ($childLevel === 0 && $outermostClass) {
                $outermostClassCode = ' class="' . $outermostClass . '" ';
                $this->setCurrentClass($child, $outermostClass);
            }

            if ($this->shouldAddNewColumn($colBrakes, $counter)) {
                $html .= '</ul></li><li class="column"><ul>';
            }

            $html .= '<li ' . $this->_getRenderedMenuItemAttributes($child) . '>';
            $html .= '<a href="' . $child->getUrl() . '" ' . $outermostClassCode . '><span>' . $this->escapeHtml(
                $child->getName()
            ) . '</span></a>' . $this->_addSubMenu(
                $child,
                $childLevel,
                $childrenWrapClass,
                $limit
            ) . '</li>';
            $counter++;
        }

        if (is_array($colBrakes) && !empty($colBrakes) && $limit) {
            $html = '<li class="column"><ul>' . $html . '</ul></li>';
        }

        return $html;
    }
}
```

It's the original function because I first wanted to test the override. But this makes the navbar completely disappear.

Overriding another function like _addSubMenu works, though.

Comment: check this link--- https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12249

Comment: Hm, it says the issue is fixed in develop branch, 2.2.1 but I'm having this problem in the newest version.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the very same problem and I was able to "xdebug" it: when you override the Topmenu _getHtml like this, copying the original code from the parent object, you end up trying to use/call a series of **private methods** from the parent! And because of the php visibility your descendant object does not have access to those private methods.

This also explains why you were able to override a different method without problems: the _addSubMenu method is not calling any private methods, only protected which is ok.

The list of private methods _getHtml calls is: removeChildrenWithoutActiveParent, getChildLevel, shouldAddNewColumn and setCurrentClass. I just copied them to my own descendant class.